Null Exception when using my own class derived from ITableEntity
Trying to retrieve some data from Azure Table Storage using Azure.Data.Tables
The below code, when using TableEntity works fine but when I use my own class derived from ITableEntity I get an exception at the foreach when it's trying to get the data.
Pageable<TaskInfo> tasks = tableClient.Query<TaskInfo>(t => t.PartitionKey == "20210325");
Pageable<TableEntity> tasks2 = tableClient.Query<TableEntity>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '20210325'");

foreach (var task2 in tasks2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{task2.GetString("TaskDescription")}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"The query returned {tasks2.Count()} entities.");

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.TaskDescription);
}
Console.WriteLine($"The query returned {tasks2.Count()} entities.");

public class TaskInfo : ITableEntity
{
    public string? PartitionKey { get; set; } = "";
    public string? RowKey { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
    ...
}

System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Int64.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.TablesTypeBinder.TryGet[T](BoundMemberInfo memberInfo, IDictionary`2 source, T& value)
   at Azure.Core.TypeBinder`1.BoundMemberInfo`1.Deserialize(TExchange source, Object o, TypeBinder`1 binderImplementation)
   at Azure.Core.TypeBinder`1.BoundTypeInfo.Deserialize[T](TExchange source)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.DictionaryTableExtensions.ToTableEntity[T](IDictionary`2 entity, BoundTypeInfo typeInfo)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.DictionaryTableExtensions.ToTableEntityList[T](IReadOnlyList`1 entityList)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.<>c__DisplayClass56_0`1.<Query>b__0(Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)
   at Azure.Core.PageableHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<CreateEnumerable>b__0(String _, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)
   at Azure.Core.PageableHelpers.FuncPageable`1.<AsPages>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Pageable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__8.MoveNext()
   at AnalyzeImportProcesses.Program.AnalyzeRetailPriceImportProcess() in C:\Users\cward\source\repos\AnalyzeImportProcesses\AnalyzeImportProcesses\Program.cs:line 44
   at AnalyzeImportProcesses.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\cward\source\repos\AnalyzeImportProcesses\AnalyzeImportProcesses\Program.cs:line 23


Can you add a constructor for your TaskInfo class without any parameters? Something like public TaskInfo() {}. In past I have seen the deserialization failing because of that.

@GauravMantri tried it same null exception

Ok. Can you tell which line of code is throwing the exception? All we can see is that the exception is raised from line 23 and 44 in your code.

@GauravMantri it was on the foreach line is it was during the deserialization.  I did figure out the issue and have posted it as the answer and how I was able to figure it out.  Thank you for your help

Turns out one of my properties on my TaskInfo class called TaskID should of been TaskId. It would be nice if the error message was clearer on this or if there is a way to get around something like this.
The method I used to figure it out was comment out all of the properties except for what ITableEntity required and one by one uncommented them until I found the one that was causing the error.
